# What is this entity?

Tags: riddle

My first two became the chandler's downfall and woe

My last two include a fiddle, flute and cello.

Put it all together and what do you get?

An evil woman, who can turn to stone any living thing with her strange magic.

Comment: Did you mean "[chandelier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandelier)" and not "[Chandler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_(band))", "[Chandler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Chandler_(DD-206))" or "[Chandler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_Bing)"?

Comment: @ToddWilcox No, they meant [chandler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandlery), which is in fact related to the word chandelier.

Comment: @Will Ah so. This site never fails to educate. Well at least I got my *Friends* joke in.

Comment: Why the downvote all of a sudden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> Electric Light Orchestra

The first two

> Electric Lights made chandlery less important and eventually completely unneeded

The last two

> Light Orchestra; indicates light orchestral music, which often has fiddlers, flautists, and cellists

And lastly

> "Evil Woman," "Turn to Stone," "Livin' Thing," and "Strange Magic" can be found in the discography of [Electric Light Orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Light_Orchestra)

Comment: Yes.  Too easy apparently...

Comment: @APrough I was only able to get it because I recognized the ELO stuff from _Xanadu_ of all places (it was good for something!!), and the first two lines took me a while.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a wild guess that I can't justify to the clues, but I don't know enough about the subject to be sure it's wrong.

> Gorgonzola?

Trying to justify it:

> The last hint made me think Medusa, who's a gorgon. I searched Medusa and Chandler and there is some mention of Chandler within a book called the "Gorgon's Gaze", and I didn't know if "zo" "la" could be musical terms (with "la" at least being a note).

Comment: If you can justify how a cheese is an evil woman, I'd be impressed. :/

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's the gorgon bit!

Comment: Then you have inverted the ordering of the clues listed. The whole is the evil woman, not the first two [syllables].

Comment: Please justify your answer, otherwise it is not a valid answer.